# Dynamically calling a class method when given a string as the method name

Tags: dart

Consider the following code in JavaScript:

```js
class Thing {
  foo() {console.log('foo')}
  bar() {console.log('bar')}
}

const thing = new Thing();

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  const methodName = i % 2 !== 0
    ? 'foo'
    : 'bar';

  thing[methodName](); // this bit here is the important part
}
```

Is such a thing possible in Dart? I'm looking to call a method dynamically. What's the sanctioned way of going about this in Dart? Is an if / else chain or switch the only way of doing so?

```dart
void main() {
  TestThing test = TestThing();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final method = i.isOdd
      ? 'foo'
      : 'bar';
    
    test[method](); //  ERROR: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class TestThing
  }
}

class TestThing {
  TestThing();
  
  int foo() {
    print('foo');
    return 1;
  }
  
  int bar() {
    print('bar');
    return 2;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible with the [`dart:mirrors` library](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-mirrors/dart-mirrors-library.html).
This is how it would be implemented with your example:

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class TestThing {  
  int foo() {
    print('foo');
    return 1;
  }
  
  int bar() {
    print('bar');
    return 2;
  }
}

void main() {
  TestThing test = TestThing();
  InstanceMirror mirror = reflect(test);
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final method = i.isOdd
      ? 'foo'
      : 'bar';
    
    mirror.invoke(method, []);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to use `dart:mirror` for this. You can instead implement `noSuchMethod` on your class and define here what should happen. You will need to mark your variable as `dynamic` to tell the compiler that your type errors are intended:

```
void main() {
  final dynamic test = TestThing();
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final method = i.isOdd ? 'foo' : 'bar';
    test[method]();
  }
}

class TestThing {
  TestThing();

  int foo() {
    print('foo');
    return 1;
  }

  int bar() {
    print('bar');
    return 2;
  }

  @override
  dynamic noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
    return () =>
        print('You tried to fetch: ${invocation.positionalArguments.first}');
  }
}
```

Output:

```
You tried to fetch: bar
You tried to fetch: foo
You tried to fetch: bar
You tried to fetch: foo
You tried to fetch: bar
```